# Why predicate locks cannot be acquired through an explicit locking query syntax

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql, transactions

Most RDBMS allow acquiring a shared on exclusive lock on the rows being selected. For example, PostgreSQL has a syntax like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM post 
WHERE id=10 
FOR SHARE;
```

Using FOR SHARE, we can acquire shared locks even in READ_COMMITTED isolation level, and non-repeatable read phenomena can be prevented without actually using the REPEATABLE_READ transaction isolation.

But to prevent phantom reads, SERIALIZABLE is the only way to do it. Why there isn't an explicit locking syntax to acquire a predicate lock as well?

To my knowledge, I don't recall seeing any such construct in Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: as i remember FOR SHARE have same semantic as SELECT FOR UPDATE. you are receive READ LOCK for reading on all tables involved to select.
in the other hand, SERIALIZABLE lvl is provides WRITE LOCK to you too. also, SELECT FOR UPDATE have the same semantic in Oracle e.g.

Comment: FOR SHARE acquires a read lock, while FOR UPDATE gives you a write lock instead. When using SERIALIZABLE, the database acquires both SHARED locks (to prevent fuzzy reads) on all retrieved rows and also range/predicate locks too (to prevent phantom reads).

Comment: Why would you want to enforce a transaction isolation level at each query rather than just using the transaction isolation level?  In Oracle, you could always use a flashback query to a SCN to avoid phantom reads (which is what Oracle is doing under the covers if you set the transaction isolation level to serializable).  That wouldn't require any sort of lock or any sort of blocking of other sessions.  But it wouldn't have the same behavior of throwing an ORA-08177: Cannot serialize access for this transaction error for non-serializable modifications.

Comment: Given that each database that you list will likely have a different answer, however, I'd expect this question to be either "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: The isolation level is set at the connection level, and all transactions started from that particular connection will inherit it. I thought of a finer grained control, where I could prevent some anomalies using explicit locking while on a lower isolation level (READ_COMMITTED)

Comment: It could be flagged as not appropriate to SO rules, but I think the reason is universal and it has to do with the conflict resolution detection mechanism.

Comment: I really wanted this kind of support in PostgreSQL by your same reasons. Without such support the only safe alternative is to lock the tables in the predicate, thus potentially affecting concurrency too much for large tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostreSQL Serializable isolation level is based on so called [Serializable Snapshot Isolation](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Serializable), which use predicate locks not for actual locking, but for monitoring for conditions which could create a serialization anomaly. This mechanism works only at Serializable level; there is no way to use predicate locks at lower levels.

But to prevent phantom reads, you actually need just Repeatable Read isolation level in PostgreSQL (despite of what SQL standard says about isolation levels). See [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/transaction-iso.html) for details.

As for Oracle, it doesn't have predicate locks at all. Its Serializable isolation level uses snapshot isolation (same as Repeatable Read in PostgreSQL), which prevents phantom reads but allows [other serialization anomalies](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SSI).

I have no information about SQL Server and MySQL.

Comment: I downvoted because this does not really answer the question. This asked why there is no explicit support for predicate locks in PostgreSQL by means of SQL syntax. For example, calling `select count(*) from cars where color = 'blue' for update` could create a kind of "predicate lock" that would block attempts to add to, delete from, and update rows in the returned set (which is like what predicate locks do in SERIALIZABLE mode).

Comment: It already does that for concrete rows, but it doesn't create a lock on *"anything matching `color = 'blue'` even if it didn't exist or wasn't visible at the time of the initial query"*. That'd be handy, but experience in other DBMSes shows it's deadlock prone and hard to make perform well, so in practice Pg offers `SERIALIZABLE` isolation as an alternative. You can do application level logic to emulate predicate locks with advisory locking, or using sentinel rows, unique constraints and row locking.

Answer (score 1):

The standard doesn't specify predicate locks, or that predicate locking must be used to implement `SERIALIZABLE`. It only specifies the anomalies `SERIALIZABLE` must prevent... and most DBMSes don't actually fully comply there.

In PostgreSQL's case there's no explicit predicate locking syntax because there are no predicate locks. PostgreSQL uses something more like optimistic locking for `SERIALIZABLE`, where it keep track of inter-transaction dependencies and aborts if it detects a circular dependency. This doesn't follow the semantics of a lock, and wouldn't be very useful to do explicitly.

Comment: It would be useful in isolation levels weaker than SERIALIZABLE. See the comment I added in Egor's answer.